# angular 10 ssr doesn't work with request api

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

on a project i installed angular universal for SSR and i use firebase hosting and functions for deployment.

for the static text and image resources, I get the content for SEO in production, but for an API request I do not see the html code in app-root

I still use the resolver

UserService

```js
  ...
  getUsers(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrlApi + '/api/user?limit=10', super.header(this.appId));
  }
```

UserResolverService

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { UserService } from '../../core/services/user.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserResolverService implements Resolve<any> {

  constructor(private _userService: UserService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
    return this._userService.getUsers();
  }
}
```

AppRoutingModule

```js
  ...
  { path: 'display-api', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/page-display-api/page-display-api.module').then(m => m.PageDisplayApiModule), data: { preload: true },
  resolve: {
    users: UserResolverService
   }
```

PageDisplayApiComponent

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.users = this._route.snapshot.data['users'].data;
```

therefore, on the screen the users are well displayed but for SEO there is nothing in app-root

Comment: Do you get any error in your cloud function log?

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your reply

I don't understand I've been stuck for 4 days and it just worked even though I didn't do anything ...
it works now. oO

on the other hand I have an error in the firebase functions logs, here it is:
(it still works despite this error in the log)

*ssr
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'index.html' at router_ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (/workspace/dist/blog-iner-code/server/main.js:1:2464378) at CatchSubscriber.expandSegmentGroup.pipe.pipe.e [as selector] (/workspace/dist/blog-iner-code/server/main.js:1:2464039) at CatchSubscriber.error (/workspace/dist/blog-iner-code/server/main.js:1:470673) at MapSubscriber._error (/workspace/dist/blog-iner-code/server/main.js:1:367848) at MapSubscriber.error (/workspace/dist/blog-iner-code/server/main.js:1:367633) at MapSubscriber._error (/workspace/dist/blog-iner-code/server/main.js:1:367848) at MapSubscriber.error (/workspace/dist/blog-iner-code/server/main.js:1:367633) at MapSubscriber._error (/workspace/dist/blog-iner-code/server/main.js:1:367848) at MapSubscriber.error (/workspace/dist/blog-iner-code/server/main.js:1:367633) at ThrowIfEmptySubscriber._error (/workspace/dist/blog-iner-code/server/main.js:1:367848) at resolvePromise (/workspace/dist/blog-iner-code/server/main.js:1:1080094) at resolvePromise (/workspace/dist/blog-iner-code/server/main.js:1:1079071) at /workspace/dist/blog-iner-code/server/main.js:1:1081898 at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (/workspace/dist/blog-iner-code/server/main.js:1:1071198) at Object.onInvokeTask (/workspace/dist/blog-iner-code/server/main.js:1:1542199) at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (/workspace/dist/blog-iner-code/server/main.js:1:1071088) at Zone.runTask (/workspace/dist/blog-iner-code/server/main.js:1:1063763) at drainMicroTaskQueue (/workspace/dist/blog-iner-code/server/main.js:1:1074806) at ZoneTask.invokeTask (/workspace/dist/blog-iner-code/server/main.js:1:1072847) at ZoneTask.options.useG.invoke (/workspace/dist/blog-iner-code/server/main.js:1:1072612)*

Comment: happens exactly the same to me. Did you fixed it?